# MySQL distinct combination of two columns

Tags: mysql

Consider the following table:

```
 A | B | ...
-------------
 1 | 1 | ...
 1 | 1 | ...
 1 | 9 | ...
 3 | 1 | ...
 3 | 2 | ...
```

I want to treat every row as distinct only when the combination of A and B has not been seen yet.  So every one of those rows is distinct except for the first two.  Then I want to grab the entire row for every distinct entry.

I know I could restructure the table to have an id that I create from A and B which would make this easier, but I want to avoid that if possible.  I am not very good with MySQL queries so I don't exactly know where to start with something like this.

Is such a query possible?  If so please explain what that query is and how it works.  Otherwise explain why it is not possible and tell me what the best solution is.

EDIT:

I realized my wording was unclear.  I said I wanted to grab every distinct entry, but that was incorrect.  What I meant was I want every distinct entry, then I also want only one of every non-distinct entry.  I still want one of the first two rows and it shouldn't matter which one I get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in MySQL using the group by extensions:

```
select t.*
from table t
group by a, b
having count(*) = 1;
```

The `having` clause counts the number of matching rows and only includes the unique rows.

By the way, this is a nice example where the MySQL group by extensions are useful.

EDIT:

You can also express this without using the extensions, and it might be more efficient with an index on `table(A, B)`:

```
select t.*
from table t
where 1 = (select count(*) from table t2 where t2.a = t.a and t2.b = t.b);
```

EDIT:

You can still use the `group by` extensions:

```
select t.*
from table t
group by a, b;
```

Do note that the documentation does *not* guarantee that all the columns in the `select` will come from the same row.  In practice, they do come from the same, but arbitrary row.

Without a unique identifier, you cannot do this with an `exists` method.  You could do it with variables, but the above should be fine.

Comment: @echo_Me . . . There are some very good moderators, including from the SQL side of the forum.  Although I periodically have the bandwidth to be obsessed with StackOverflow, I don't know if I can make the ongoing commitment, for a full year.  Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, after reading this answer I realized my wording was very poor.  I have added an edit to explain it better.